# is there a way to create alerts for virtual machine, storage account resources in azure log analytics using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics, azure-storage-account

'''
This is the approach i followed to create the alerts at resource level ( storage account).I am looking to create the alerts for different resources in log analytics instead of creating at resource level
'''

```
data "azurerm_storage_account" "stro" {
  name                = "straccount18"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "AlertForLog" {
  name                = "metricalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  scopes              = [data.azurerm_storage_account.stro.id]
  description         = "Alert generation demo"

  window_size         = "PT1H"
  severity = 0

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    metric_name      = "UsedCapacity"
    aggregation      = "Average"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 85
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by setting up query rules alerts as described in here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_alert and enabling Storage Analytics as described in here

Query Storage Analytics Logs in Log Analytics: https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/query-azure-storage-analytics-logs-in-azure-log-analytics/

Sotage Analytics: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-analytics

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers (they're not valid answers, and require someone to visit offsite resources to figure out what to do).